# How to display data as array format using python

Tags: python, arrays, django, arraylist

```
def index(request):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="pwd", db="highchart_with_django")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT categories,tokyo,london,new_york,berlin FROM basic_line_chart")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row is not None:
       print row
       row = cursor.fetchone()
    return render(request, "linechart.html")
```

It's giving output like below:

```
('Sep', Decimal('7.00'), Decimal('3.90'), Decimal('-0.20'), Decimal('-0.90'))
('Oct', Decimal('6.90'), Decimal('4.20'), Decimal('0.80'), Decimal('0.60'))
```

expecting output:

```
 ["Sep", "7.00", "3.90", "-0.20", "-0.90"],["Oct", "6.90", "4.20", "0.80", "0.60"]
```

How can i achieve this. please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blindly converting everything to strings (because you haven't been specific):

```
def index(request):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="pwd", db="highchart_with_django")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT categories,tokyo,london,new_york,berlin FROM basic_line_chart")
    rows = [[str(field) for field in row] for row in cursor]
    for row in rows:
        print(row)
    return render(request, "linechart.html")
```

I'm not sure this solves your problem. Do you want all the `Decimal` converted to strings? Some kind of floating point number is probably more useful for charting.

Comment: each row seperate with comma. how to do that?

Comment: Try `print(rows)`. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

According to this link http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html `fetchone()` returns a tuple.

To convert that to a list, simply cast it.

```
row = list(cursor.fetchone())
```

You can then iterate the list to get them in the proper format you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't 100% clear but if you're really just trying to get a list of strings:

```
>>> for row in cursor.fetchall():
...     print [str(col) for col in row]
...
['Sep', '7.00', '3.90', '-0.20', '-0.90']
['Oct', '6.90', '4.20', '0.80', '0.60']
```

Answer (score 1):

please try

`row = cursor.dictfetchall()` #which gives dict

`row = cursor.fetchall()` #gives a list.

Output :-

```
["Sep", "7.00", "3.90", "-0.20", "-0.90"],["Oct", "6.90", "4.20", "0.80", "0.60"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
def index(request):
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="user", passwd="pwd", db="highchart_with_django")
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT categories,tokyo,london,new_york,berlin FROM basic_line_chart")
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    while row is not None:
       print row
       row = list(cursor.fetchone())
    return render(request, "linechart.html")
```